# Hide the params hash and replace it with a cleaner URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

The default URL generated after a get request in Rails isn't very nice to look at.

Using the meta_search gem in a Rails 3 application, I've created a select menu to filter a list of articles by category. The code looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @search, :url => articles_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :category_name_equals, "Filter by category:" %>  
  <%= f.collection_select :category_name_equals, 
    Category.all(:order => "name"), :name, :name, :include_blank => true %> 
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>

<table>  
  <tr>  
    <th>Title</th>  
    <th>Category</th>  
  </tr>  
  <% for article in @articles %>  
  <tr>  
    <td><%= link_to article.title, article %></td> 
    <td><%= article.category.name %></td>
  </tr>  
  <% end %>  
</table>
```

Right now, when the form is submitted, a lengthy URL is returned containing the params hash:

```
http://localhost:3000/articles?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search[category_name_equals]=
Reviews&commit=Search
```

I want to keep the URL as clean as possible, for example:

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/category/reviews
```

or

```
http://localhost:3000/articles?category=reviews
```

What are some solutions to make the params hash URL more readable by humans?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a form with get method. it's an HTML issue.

You need add some Javascript to convert your URL to pretty URL or you can get URL in your controller in your rails application and redirect to your pretty URL.

Answer (score 0):

Like shingara said, don't use a form at all. Instead use a list of links, and fancy things up with some css/js that makes your list behave/look like a drop-down menu:

```
<ul>
  <% Category.all.each do |c| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to(c.name, :controller => :articles, :action => :browse, :category => c.tag) %>
    </li> 
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

For your routes, you'll want something like this, but DRYer:

```
routes.connect '/articles/browse/:category', :controller => :articles, :action => :browse
```

You can find many examples of CSS/JS dropdowns very easily: http://bit.ly/dRtQNd

You can find examples of *good* CSS/JS dropdown menus with considerably more effort ... unless you give up just ask for advice on stack overflow again :-). (Coding rudimentary versions of standard UI components from scratch is simple these days using jQuery and whatnot, so lots of people do it. Coding ones that "feel right" is actually very hard; fewer people do that!)

P.S. That `form_for @search` looks utterly weird. This is not what `form_for @your_model_object` was meant for...